# Should i create 2 tables for probucts in my db-PHP & Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got some question(**s**)
How many tables should i create for my products ?

2???=products & products pics???

if yes then my mysql tables will be like that ? 
1.products= p_id, p_name, p_descr, p_pieces, p_categ, p_subcateg(??) &

2.products_pics= pp_id, product_id, thumb, image, type (???)

Well im a little bit confused cause i think its not so necessary to use products_pics into the db anymore .

My product entries will be around 3.000 for the beginning . Can someone tell me what im going to write-do ??? Thank you very much !

Comment: _Note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing mysql databases. Unless you're modifying that applications core, you're not actually working with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: create only one table for the products and for image take p_image column.

for multiple images of product insert formatted string as "image1.png,imgae2.png"

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj - You should _never_ insert multiple comma separated values into one column. That is a _very_ bad practices with some serious downsides. [Read about Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

Comment: Create two tables. One with `products` and one with `product_images`. The product images tables should simply contain: `id, product_id, image`. The `product_id` is a foreign key to the `id` field in your `products` table.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay.. thanks for the information :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the table you've suggested is okey..just give proper foreign relation and indexes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make 3 tables

- `products`
- `images`
- `products_images`

In table `products` you have `id_prod` (primary key), `name_prod`, and other.

In table `images` you have `id_img` (primary key), `name_img` or `img_src`.

In table `products_images` you link images with products, and structure should be like `id` (primary), `id_prod`, `id_img`.

This way you will not have a duplicate content in tables.

Comment: thanks a lot that was the answer i was looking for !

Comment: @Marilou Antonios Vasilia I'm glad that I could help. Mark my answer as accepted then :)

Answer (score -1):

If you only have images / documents pertaining to products only, and you want to store them in your database, you can store the image as blob/longblob directly inside the products table as p_image for example.
But when you want to retrieve it you will get the binary data, so you should write it to a file or convert it to view it as image under browser.

And if you have multiple images for the same product, you should create another table and use p_id as foreign key.

However, it is not advisable to store images in the database, for more information please refer to : [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: Images are files and should be stored on the file system unless you have a _really_ good reason not to (there are situations when storing small images in the DB might make sense, even though I can't think of any right now). Also, even if the products only have one image now, specs change so it's better to do it more dynamic from the start (like having a separate product_image-table with filenames).

Comment: no need to save the images as blob and write it to a file each time..there's no need of it..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in my answer i stated if marilou wanted to store them in the database, that's the way to do it

Comment: Sure, but we should explain that this is a bad way of doing it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson indeed!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated the answer, and thanks for clarification !